# In dark mode, the input for Watched Tags flashes white

Tags: bug, tag-watching, dark-mode

There is a problem with the *Watched Tags* panel.

I've been trying to search some tags (in the dark mode) and when I wrote my query, Search Input went white for some seconds, like in the below image.

I think the input background color should not be changed.

[image: white flash after the tag is finished being typed, as the suggestions are shown]

Comment: The culprit is `ac_loading` class which has `.ac_loading { background: hsl(0,0%,100%) url(../../Img/progress-dots.gif?v=679ddd617b7d) right center no-repeat; }` style.

Comment: yeah, it's true. i think this should be correct in the website.